# Why is wind sporadic in a Boston northeaster?

Tags: meteorology, wind, storms

We are having a tough little northeaster in Boston, USA, right now and one oddity that I notice is the wind pattern. There will be complete calm for 3-5 minutes, then the wind will blow hard in gusts for 2-3 minutes and stop. Even stranger, the wind blows from a different direction each time.

Why is the wind like this?

Comment: A "northeaster" is rather nonspecific, so I've edited the title to include the location, and edited the text to specify which Boston. I'm assumed that it's the Boston in the US, because people who forget to specify a country are usually American ;-), but if this is wrong please change it!

Comment: @Flyto Yes, Boston, the Hub of the Universe (https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Hub+of+the+Universe). I assumed that anyone capable of answering this question would know where the center of the universe is.